# Moving a gtk widget anchored within a gtk textview

Tags: gtk, gtk#

How can i move a Gtk Widget which is anchored inside a Gtk Textview? Selecting text and moving them around inside the Textview works as expected, but when a Widget is selected too, it disappears after the movement. What's the correct way of implementing movable widgets inside a textview?

Comment: Excellent question! I think it should work as you describe; if not, perhaps file a bug report on bugzilla.gnome.org.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is GTK+ bug - a small test using the native C-API showed the same behavior - filed a bug over at bugzilla.gnome.org under id [667739](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=667739) in case someone here wants to follow it's progress.